# Do Qt::QueuedConnection signals always invoke in order?

Tags: c++, qt

Related to [Qt: Do events get processed in order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733022/qt-do-events-get-processed-in-order)

Do  `Qt::QueuedConnection` signals **always** get invoked in order?

So:

```
void A::func()
{
    emit first_signal();
    emit second_signal();
}
```

If these are **both** connected by `Qt::QueuedConnection` to slots will they always be invoked in the order `first_signal()` then `second_signal()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the fact that [bug(s) regarding the event prioritization](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-19637) are still being fixed very recently (target version 4.8.0), better don't rely on it. The observation that docs avoid any bold statements most probably means that the devs are simply not so sure.

Answer (score 1):

If the documentation does not state it, you should rather not assume it.

Comment: Indeed so; but I was wondering if it was documented elsewhere that I have - until now - missed.